# Creating multiple database dynamically in MERN

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

We are creating a web portal in MERN for office services where the instance for any new office can be created online. In this case the database name also gets created dynamically for any office. The superadmin will have the frontend to create any new instance for the respective offices.
The database of super admin will have a collection for names of newly created databases. These names are to be used dynamically in node/Express to create connection to second database.
What will be the best way to connect the backend to the main (super admin) database and dynamically to newly created databases upon choosing option in frontend. After connection to the newly created database one sub admin in the new database is to be created by the superadmin.

Comment: I would caution you to use one database, you can almost always benefit from doing such... Otherwise you are going to have to store key credentials for every database you have to connect to... Then you have to deal with all the work of deciding what database to access... No it's probably best (again I don't fully know your situation) to use a single database.

Comment: But if i use the same database, i have to create all collections multiple times in that database for different office instances. That would create a mess.

Comment: Not at all... If I understand your situation correctly all you have to do is identify which office it goes to.... Largely that just means creating an offices table with an id and whatever other information you want to store about that office... Then you create a relation between the current tables and this office table... Anytime you do a select/insert/update you can always update by the office id... Therefore all of the data is mixed, but can be queried by office.